# 5 digit numbers by using 1 2 3

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many 5-digit numbers are there by using only 1,2 and 3?

It's not so complicated, but I don't have a solution and friend's answer is different, can't figure it out myself.

EDIT: I typed the question text totally wrong, I forgot that all 3 digits must appear at least once, I apologize

Comment: The answer should be $3^5$.

Comment: What is your friend's answer?  How were you going to solve the problem?

Comment: I started by finding combinations of those 3 digits, and then using permutations of those to find the result, which ended up being 6!. My friend used a different approach, she got a 60*9, which is different. Maybe it's neither, just interested in result, seems simple, and yet it's bugging me :)

Comment: You need inclusion-exclusion here.

Comment: As in? Subtracting from total number of options? Seems like I did it wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $3^5=243$ ways of using all $3$ digits to create a $5$-digit number.

These include possibilities such as $21221$, $31313$ and $11111$, so we need to remove these to get the final total.

There are $2^5=32$ ways for each $2$ digits combination, and there are $3$ such combinations, so we subtract $3\cdot32=96$.

But each $2$ digit combination also removes $2$ of $11111,22222,33333$, and we only wish to remove them once, so we need to add $3$ back.

Therefore the total number is $243-96+3=150$.

Comment: This does seem correct, I completely whiffed. Can you please elaborate some more on 2^5 for each 2 digits combination, that part is a bit confusing, where do I get that from. Apart from that, this answer is great, thank you so much.

Comment: there are 3 2digit combo's, namely 12,13,23. each produces a distinct set of values, except for 11111,22222,33333, each of which appear in 2 of them.

Comment: Oh, alright, I got it, so 12 combination will remove both 11111 and 22222 and so on. Thank you very much for your answer.